# Roles assigned to each user POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, data-dictionary

i'm trying to make a query that shows the users and all the roles that they have, i already know how to ask about the roles of one particular user:

```
 SELECT oid, rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE
 pg_has_role( 'name_of_user', oid, 'member');
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`USERS` are themselves `ROLES` that can login. `CREATE USER` is actually [just an alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createuser.html). What you probably want is some kind of query that psql issues with `\du` as a starting point. You can see what psql issues with `-E`,

```
********* QUERY **********
SELECT r.rolname, r.rolsuper, r.rolinherit,
  r.rolcreaterole, r.rolcreatedb, r.rolcanlogin,
  r.rolconnlimit, r.rolvaliduntil,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
, r.rolreplication
, r.rolbypassrls
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
ORDER BY 1;
**************************
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i found the way to do it, if anyone is interested:

```
SELECT r.rolname as "Users",    ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
     FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
     JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
     WHERE m.member = r.oid) as "Assigned roles"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
ORDER BY 1;
```